# How do I share ansible variables across hosts using vars_prompt

Tags: ansible

In ansible, I do some code on a remote machine, and then I want to use the result from the `vars_prompt` again on a different host.  I've searched around, and the docs make it sound like i should use `{{ hostvars.local_server_name_in_vagrant_group.local_username }}`, using my example below to set the context.  However, it says that the index from the dictionary doesn't exist when referencing `hostvars`.  Instead, as shown below, I simply do a `vars_prompt` twice.  Gross!  Any tips?

BTW, there's also discussion on whether or not *using* vars_prompt is a great idea.  I have confirmed that for my usage, indeed, I do want to use vars_prompt.  Thanks!

---

```
- hosts: vagrant
  vars_prompt:
    local_username: "enter your desired local username"

... remote task activity using local_username...

- hosts: localhost
  connection: local

  vars_prompt:
    local_username: "enter your desired local username, again (please)  

... host task activity, also using local_username ...
```

Comment: I don’t think `vars_prompt` can fit your need, unless you have a specific usage you don’t explain here. Why don’t you use a variable file instead of a `vars_prompt`? Can you elaborate why it does not fit your situation?

Comment: You can use set_facts to register your variable as a fact of the current host and access it from a different one. I do not think standard variables are stored after the role/tasks.

Comment: thanks @jiop.  i had seen `set_facts`, but it didn't register.  sure enough, on second visit, it did the trick.  much appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As I said in the comment to the question :

You can use set_facts to register your variable as a fact of the current host and access it from a different one. I do not think standard variables are stored after the role/tasks.

Here is an example :

```
    - name: First
      connection: local
      hosts: host1
      tasks:
        - name: register real root user to localhost facts
          set_fact: fact_for_host1="1"

    - name: Second
      connection: local
      hosts: host2
      tasks:
        - debug: msg="{{ hostvars['host1']['fact_for_host1'] }}"
```

Note that the `connection: local` is present only for local tests purpose.

Comment: I do want to debug the value of other variable but store it in another variable...

Comment: @bosari Please share your answer if you are able to store it another variable